# Cassandra: Migrate keyspace data from Multinode cluster to SingleNode Cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have a keyspace in a multi-node cluster in QA environment. I want to copy that keyspace to my local single-node cluster. Is there any direct way to do this? I can't afford to write some code like SSTableLoader implementation at this point of time. Please suggest the quickest way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Make sure you have plenty of free disk space on your new node and that you've properly set replication factor and consistency levels in your tests/build for your new, single node "cluster"**

First, restore the exact schema from the old cluster to your new node. After that the data can be loaded in two ways:

1.) Execute the "sstableloader" utility on every node in your old cluster and point it at your new node. sstableloader is token aware, but in your case it will end up shipping all data to your new, single node cluster.

```
sstableloader -d NewNode /Path/To/OldCluster/SStables
```

2.) Snapshot the keyspace and copy the raw sstable files from the snapshot folders of each table in your old cluster to your new node.  Once they're all there, copy the files to their corresponding table directory and run "nodetool refresh."

```
# Rinse and repeat for all tables    
nodetool snapshot -t MySnapshot
cd /Data/keyspace/table-UUID/snapshots/MySnapshot/
rsync -avP ./*.db User@NewNode:/NewData/Keyspace/table-UUID
...
# when finished, exec the following for all tables in your new node
nodetool refresh keyspace table
```

Option #1 is probably best because it will stream the data and compact naturally on the new node. It's also less manual work. Option #2 is good, quick, and dirty if you don't have a direct line from one cluster to the other. You probably won't notice much difference since it's probably a relatively small keyspace for QA.

Comment: I used the first option and it worked like a charm. Thank you man. Saved my day. One correction though, the command will contain 'd' instead of 'D'

sstableloader -d NewNode /Path/To/OldCluster/SStables

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out. Fixed the argument capitalization (too much time messing around with the JVM options :P)

Comment: @BlakeAtkinson i tried the first option but it say:   Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve endpoint ranges: